# MQTTで、Javascriptを用いてブラウザにSubscribeの実現

Tags: javascript, mqtt

MQTTで、JavaScriptを用いてブラウザにSubscribeの実現を思考しています。
JavaScriptソースは次の通りです。
mqttws31.jsファイルは、index2.htmlと同じディレクトリに配置済みです。
ブラウザ上では何も起こらず、webコンソールで見てもMQTTサーバに接続
アクションが発生していないように見えます。

```
// MQTTのクライアント
var client;
// ClientIDを指定
var clientId = 'clientid-123456789';
// Sangoへの接続
function connect() {
    var user_name = 'AAAAAA@github';
    var pass = '*************';
    var wsurl = 'ws://lite.mqtt.shiguredo.jp/mqtt';
    // WebSocketURLとClientIDからMQTT Clientを作成
    client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsurl, clientId);
    // 接続
    client.connect({
        userName: user_name,
        password: pass,
        onSuccess: onConnect,
        onFailure: failConnect
    });
}
// 接続失敗
function failConnect(e) {
    console.log('connect failed');
    console.log(e);
}
// 接続成功
function onConnect() {
    console.log('onConnect');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/

によりますと、サンプルコードが掲載されているようですが、
現在どのようなエラーが出ているのですか？

また、引数の２番目は ポート番号の設定のように見受けられます。

new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsurl, clientId);

の部分を、

new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsurl, Number(location.port), clientId);

とすると書いてあります。

websocketを使うということならば、事前にHTTPセッションが張られていることが条件です。
なお、websocketのロケーションは httpsセッションである場合、　wss://となります。

Sangoサーバーをお使いのようなので、サーバーに基づく仕様の問い合わせも十分に行ったほうが良いかと考えます。